# Handling exceptions when chaining Futures in guava

Tags: java, concurrency, guava, future

Regarding handling exceptions in the following code:

```
ListenableFuture<BufferedImage> imgFuture = downloadExecutor
                    .submit(new Downloader(url));
            ListenableFuture<BufferedImage> resizeFuture = Futures.transformAsync(
                    imgFuture, new AsyncFunction<BufferedImage, BufferedImage>()
                    {
                        @Override
                        public ListenableFuture<BufferedImage> apply(
                                BufferedImage input) throws Exception
                        {
                            ListenableFuture<BufferedImage> resizedFuture = null;
                            if (input != null)
                            {
                                resizedFuture = actionExecutor
                                        .submit(new ResizeImageAction(input));
                            }
                            return resizedFuture;
                        }
                    });

            ListenableFuture<BufferedImage> grayFuture = Futures
                    .transformAsync(resizeFuture, input -> {
                        return actionExecutor
                                .submit(new ToGrayImageAction(input));
                    });
```

Assuming that every action sumbitted to an executor can raise an exception, how will this code behave.

Does the `transformAsync()` method knows to not chain nulls or futures that raised exceptions?? Will using `CheckedFuture` help me here? If so, how should I use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It knows about thrown exception, but doesn't know about nulls because it's perfectly legal value. If exception will be thrown in the first `ListenableFuture`, then it will be propagated to the all transformers: their `onFailure` callbacks will be invoked, but not their transformation (because there is no value to transform).

Javadoc to `transformAsync`:

> @return A future that holds result of the function (if the input succeeded) or the original input's failure (if not)

Simple example:

```
ListenableFuture<Integer> nullFuture = executor.submit(() -> null);
ListenableFuture<Integer> exceptionFuture = executor.submit(() -> {
    throw new RuntimeException();
});

// Replace first argument with exceptionFuture to get another result
ListenableFuture<Integer> transformer = Futures.transformAsync(nullFuture, i -> {
    System.out.println(i);
    return Futures.immediateCheckedFuture(1);
}, executor);

Futures.addCallback(transformer, new FutureCallback<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(Integer result) {
        System.out.println(result);
  }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
        System.out.println(t);
  }
});
```

For the `nullFuture` "null and 1" will be printed, whereas for `exceptionFuture` only "java.lang.RuntimeException" will be printed, because exception was propagated to its transformer.

Comment: hmmm So If I want to chain several 'transformAsync', I must use 'Futures.addCallback()'?

Comment: @whomaniac No, you shouldn't, this is just an example to show that transformation will not occur if exception is thrown. Callback is used to print it only, not for chain transforms